# PHP New line will NOT print

Tags: php, email, line, new-operator

I've been looking for about an hour now, google is not being my friend. I've changed my code, added \n\r, added plain text formatting, html formatting...

The email is printing as such:

```
Below is the site survey information for test Restaurant Name: test Contact Name: test Walk-Thru Contact Name: test Site Surveyor: Brandon Projected Install Date: test Projected Opening Date: test Projected Completion Date: test
Item(s) Needed: test
Priority Level: Necessary for Install
Item(s) Needed: 
Priority Level: Necessary for Install
Item(s) Needed: 
Priority Level: Necessary for Install
```

Only the first few lines are printing together, but everything after completion date is printing on new lines. Here's the code for the message thus far:

```
//Prepare content

$subject = "Site Survey Information";
$from_header = "From: $formval_RestaurantName";
$headers .= "Content-type: textrn";

$to = "$formval_receiver";




$contents .= "Below is the site survey information for $formval_RestaurantName\r\n";
$contents .= "Restaurant Name: $formval_RestaurantName\r\n";
$contents .= "Contact Name: $formval_ContactName\r\n"; 
$contents .= "Walk-Thru Contact Name: $formval_walkthru\r\n";
$contents .= "Site Surveyor: $formval_surveyor\r\n";
$contents .= "Projected Install Date: $formval_install\r\n";
$contents .= "Projected Opening Date: $formval_open\r\n";
$contents .= "Projected Completion Date: $formval_finish\r\n";
$contents .= "Item(s) Needed: $formval_items1\r\n";
$contents .= "Priority Level: $formval_priority_1\r\n";
$contents .= "Item(s) Needed: $formval_items2\r\n";
$contents .= "Priority Level: $formval_priority_2\r\n";
$contents .= "Item(s) Needed: $formval_items3\r\n";
$contents .= "Priority Level: $formval_priority_3\r\n";
$contents .= "Item(s) Needed: $formval_items4\r\n";
$contents .= "Priority Level: $formval_priority_4\r\n";
$contents .= "Item(s) Needed: $formval_items5\r\n";
$contents .= "Priority Level: $formval_priority_5\r\n";
$contents .= "Item(s) Needed: $formval_items6\r\n";
$contents .= "Priority Level: $formval_priority_6\r\n";
$contents .= "Item(s) Needed: $formval_items7\r\n";
$contents .= "Priority Level: $formval_priority_7\r\n";
$contents .= "Item(s) Needed: $formval_items8\r\n";
$contents .= "Priority Level: $formval_priority_8\r\n";
$contents .= "Item(s) Needed: $formval_items9\r\n";
$contents .= "Priority Level: $formval_priority_9\r\n";
$contents .= "Item(s) Needed: $formval_items10\r\n";
$contents .= "Priority Level: $formval_priority_10\r\n";
$contents .= "Item(s) Needed: $formval_items11\r\n";
$contents .= "Priority Level: $formval_priority_11\r\n";
$contents .= "Item(s) Needed: $formval_items12\r\n";
$contents .= "Priority Level: $formval_priority_12\r\n";
$contents .= "Item(s) Needed: $formval_items13\r\n";
$contents .= "Priority Level: $formval_priority_13\r\n";
$contents .= "Item(s) Needed: $formval_items14\r\n";
$contents .= "Priority Level: $formval_priority_14\r\n";
$contents .= "Item(s) Needed: $formval_items15\r\n";
$contents .= "Priority Level: $formval_priority_15\r\n";
```

What else can I do to get it to print new lines?

Comment: what is "textrn" in the Content-type ?

Comment: Which email client are you seeing no newlines being printed in, or are you just viewing it in a browser? While email HTML is generally about as finicky as it gets, the basics (like `<BR/>`) still work pretty much across the board. For each time you need the text to start on a new line, you should tell PHP to print a `<br/>`

Comment: I saw on one site, someone said that would convert it to a plain text email. Since I've been working on this code for a month and it's still not really working, I've become desperate enough to try anything.

Comment: This is outlook. Only the first 8 contents are not printing on new lines. Everything after projected completion date will print on a new line. The email will only be received by one person and will be viewed through outlook.

Comment: replace `$headers .= "Content-type: text"; `, the give the full original message you received, not copypaste from outlook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've seen this before. There may be a bug in PHP with using \r\n right after an embedded variable.

Try this syntax and see if it works.

```
$contents .= 'Restaurant Name: ' . $formval_RestaurantName . "\r\n";
```

Comment: @meze I think it's a PHP bug, but I wasn't able to find a report on it. It doesn't always happen, but if you put escape characters right after a variable inside double quotes the escaped characters don't always get parsed correctly. You could probably do something like `$contents .= "Restaurant Name: {$formval_RestaurantName}\r\n";` also.

Answer (score 0):

try using PHP_EOL constant
or
separate variable and newline with a space:
"Projected Completion Date: $formval_finish \r\n";

Answer (score 0):

If it is being read as HTML, then \n is treated as a whitespace, not a new line. Just use `<br>` instead.